# LSH (Locality Sensitive Hashning)-based neighbor search

Tags: c#, algorithm, search, hash, neighbours

Say, I have a point cloud of 30,000 points in 3D. I want to count the neighbors for each point at a cut-off distance.

the following code always shows the neighbor count as `1` no matter what the coordinate values are:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Point3D
{
    public double X { get; set; }  // X-coordinate of the point
    public double Y { get; set; }  // Y-coordinate of the point
    public double Z { get; set; }  // Z-coordinate of the point

    public Point3D(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    public double GetDistance(Point3D point)
    {
        double dx = X - point.X;  // Calculate the difference in X-coordinates
        double dy = Y - point.Y;  // Calculate the difference in Y-coordinates
        double dz = Z - point.Z;  // Calculate the difference in Z-coordinates

        return Math.Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz);  // Calculate and return the Euclidean distance between two 3D points
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 17;  // Initialize the hash value with an arbitrary prime number

        // Update the hash value using the X, Y, and Z coordinates
        hash = hash * 31 + X.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 31 + Y.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 31 + Z.GetHashCode();

        return hash;  // Return the calculated hash value
    }
}

public static class NeighborCounter
{
    private static Dictionary<int, HashSet<Point3D>> hashBuckets = new Dictionary<int, HashSet<Point3D>>();

    private static void AddPoint(Point3D point, int hash)
    {
        if (!hashBuckets.TryGetValue(hash, out HashSet<Point3D> bucket))
        {
            bucket = new HashSet<Point3D>();  // Create a new HashSet for the hash if it doesn't exist
            hashBuckets[hash] = bucket;  // Add the bucket to the hashBuckets dictionary
        }

        bucket.Add(point);  // Add the point to the corresponding bucket
    }

    private static HashSet<Point3D> GetNeighbors(Point3D point, int hash)
    {
        if (hashBuckets.TryGetValue(hash, out HashSet<Point3D> neighbors))
        {
            return neighbors;  // Return the neighbors for the given hash
        }

        return null;  // Return null if there are no neighbors for the given hash
    }

  /*
  numHashes determines the range of neighboring hash values to consider when searching for neighboring points. It affects the scope of the search by specifying how many neighboring hash values, in both directions, should be considered. 
  It helps identify potential candidate points within a certain range of hash values.
  */
    public static Dictionary<Point3D, int> Search(Point3D[] points, int numHashes, double cutOffDistance)
    {
      /*
      By processing each point and adding it to the appropriate hash bucket, this loop organizes the points into separate buckets based on their hash values.
      */
        foreach (Point3D point in points)
        {
            int hash = point.GetHashCode();  // Calculate the hash value for the point
            AddPoint(point, hash);  // Add the point to the corresponding hash bucket
        }

        Dictionary<Point3D, int> pointNeighbors = new Dictionary<Point3D, int>();

        foreach (Point3D point in points)
        {
            int neighborCount = 0;  // Initialize the neighbor count for the current point
            int hash = point.GetHashCode();  // Calculate the hash value for the point

            for (int i = hash - numHashes; i <= hash + numHashes; i++)
            {
                var neighbors = GetNeighbors(point, i);  // Retrieve the neighbors for the given hash

                if (neighbors != null)
                {
                    foreach (Point3D neighbor in neighbors)
                    {
                        double distance = point.GetDistance(neighbor);  // Calculate the distance between the current point and its neighbor

                        if (distance <= cutOffDistance)  // Check if the distance is within the cutoff distance
                        {
                            neighborCount++;  // Increment the neighbor count
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            pointNeighbors[point] = neighborCount;  // Store the neighbor count for the current point
        }

        return pointNeighbors;  // Return the dictionary containing the points and their neighbor counts
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Point3D[] points = new Point3D[]
        {
            new Point3D(0, 0, 0),
            new Point3D(0, 0, 1),
            new Point3D(1, 0, 0),
            new Point3D(0, 1, 0),
            new Point3D(1, 1, 0),
            new Point3D(2, 2, 0)
        };

        double cutOffDistance = 1.5;  // The maximum distance between two points for them to be considered neighbors
        int numHashes = 100;  // The number of neighboring hashes to consider

        Dictionary<Point3D, int> pointNeighbors = NeighborCounter.Search(points, numHashes, cutOffDistance);

        foreach (var kvp in pointNeighbors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Point ({kvp.Key.X}, {kvp.Key.Y}, {kvp.Key.Z}) has {kvp.Value} neighbors within the cutoff distance.");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

What is the bug in the code?

---

Here is another version using Morton's hashing:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Point3D
{
    public double X { get; set; }  // X-coordinate of the point
    public double Y { get; set; }  // Y-coordinate of the point
    public double Z { get; set; }  // Z-coordinate of the point

    public Point3D(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    public double GetDistance(Point3D point)
    {
        double dx = X - point.X;  // Calculate the difference in X-coordinates
        double dy = Y - point.Y;  // Calculate the difference in Y-coordinates
        double dz = Z - point.Z;  // Calculate the difference in Z-coordinates

        return Math.Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz);  // Calculate and return the Euclidean distance between two 3D points
    }

  public ulong GetMortonHash()
    {
        ulong xBits = Part1By1((ulong)X);
        ulong yBits = Part1By1((ulong)Y);
        ulong zBits = Part1By1((ulong)Z);

        return xBits * 4 + yBits * 2 + zBits;
    }

    private ulong Part1By1(ulong value)
    {
        value &= 0x00000000FFFFFFFF; // Discard upper 32 bits (if any)
        value = (value ^ (value << 16)) & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF;
        value = (value ^ (value << 8)) & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF;
        value = (value ^ (value << 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F;
        value = (value ^ (value << 2)) & 0x3333333333333333;
        value = (value ^ (value << 1)) & 0x5555555555555555;

        return value;
    }
}

public static class NeighborCounter
{
    private static Dictionary<ulong, HashSet<Point3D>> hashBuckets 
  = new Dictionary<ulong, HashSet<Point3D>>();

    private static void AddPoint(Point3D point, ulong hash)
    {
        if (!hashBuckets.TryGetValue(hash, out HashSet<Point3D> bucket))
        {
            bucket = new HashSet<Point3D>();  // Create a new HashSet for the hash if it doesn't exist
            hashBuckets[hash] = bucket;  // Add the bucket to the hashBuckets dictionary
        }

        bucket.Add(point);  // Add the point to the corresponding bucket
    }

    private static HashSet<Point3D> GetNeighbors(Point3D point, ulong hash)
    {
        if (hashBuckets.TryGetValue(hash, out HashSet<Point3D> neighbors))
        {
            return neighbors;  // Return the neighbors for the given hash
        }

        return null;  // Return null if there are no neighbors for the given hash
    }

  /*
  numHashes determines the range of neighboring hash values to consider when searching for neighboring points. It affects the scope of the search by specifying how many neighboring hash values, in both directions, should be considered. 
  It helps identify potential candidate points within a certain range of hash values.
  */
    public static Dictionary<Point3D, int> Search(Point3D[] points, ulong numHashes, double cutOffDistance)
    {
      /*
      By processing each point and adding it to the appropriate hash bucket, this loop organizes the points into separate buckets based on their hash values.
      */
        foreach (Point3D point in points)
        {
            ulong hash = point.GetMortonHash();  // Calculate the hash value for the point
            AddPoint(point, hash);  // Add the point to the corresponding hash bucket
        }

        Dictionary<Point3D, int> pointNeighbors = new Dictionary<Point3D, int>();

        foreach (Point3D point in points)
        {
            int neighborCount = 0;  // Initialize the neighbor count for the current point
            ulong hash = point.GetMortonHash();  // Calculate the hash value for the point

            for (ulong i = hash - numHashes; i <= hash + numHashes; i++)
            {
                var neighbors = GetNeighbors(point, (ulong)i);  // Retrieve the neighbors for the given hash

                if (neighbors != null)
                {
                    foreach (Point3D neighbor in neighbors)
                    {
                        double distance = point.GetDistance(neighbor);  // Calculate the distance between the current point and its neighbor

                        if (distance <= cutOffDistance)  // Check if the distance is within the cutoff distance
                        {
                            neighborCount++;  // Increment the neighbor count
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            pointNeighbors[point] = neighborCount;  // Store the neighbor count for the current point
        }

        return pointNeighbors;  // Return the dictionary containing the points and their neighbor counts
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Point3D[] points = new Point3D[]
        {
            new Point3D(0, 0, 0),
            new Point3D(0, 0, 1),
            new Point3D(1, 0, 0),
            new Point3D(0, 1, 0),
            new Point3D(1, 1, 0),
            new Point3D(2, 2, 0)
        };

        double cutOffDistance = 1.5;  // The maximum distance between two points for them to be considered neighbors
        ulong numHashes = 100;  // The number of neighboring hashes to consider

        Dictionary<Point3D, int> pointNeighbors = NeighborCounter.Search(points, numHashes, cutOffDistance);

        foreach (var kvp in pointNeighbors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Point ({kvp.Key.X}, {kvp.Key.Y}, {kvp.Key.Z}) has {kvp.Value} neighbors within the cutoff distance.");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

This also doesn't behave as intended.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that `double.GetHashCode()` will give you hash values where `d1.GetHashCode() +1 == (d1+1).GetHashCode()`, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76608859/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/160977/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: Your original `Point3D.GetHashCode` is a fairly typical hash function. But even though you have now changed your hash function, you are still assuming that all neighbours will have morton numbers that are close. But morton numbers only guarantee that values with a close morton number are close in 3d space. Not that all close positions in 3d space have close morton numbers.

Comment: From the linked meta link above "Each site is focused on a specific topic area and it's important to respect the community", and your follow up "So what?" is also a sign of disrespect. So why should we show you any respect?

Comment: You will need to work out which nearby morton numbers to calculate, while you are searching for neighbours. Or use a completely different approach to partition space.